# python replace '?' with not successive or preceding character

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to solve a riddle, the challenge is to replace the question mark in a string by not using the previous or the following character in that string

For example:-
riddle = 'abcd?ef?'
expected_out = 'abcdiefa'

riddle = '???'
expected_out = 'aea'

This is the solution that I have tried but for some reason it isn't working

```
successor_element = ''
predecessor_element = ''
my_pre_succ_elements = []
riddle = "ab?ac?"
required_list = []
def solution(riddle):
    my_replacers = ['a','e','i']
    j = len(riddle)
    print(j)
    for e in range(0,j):
        req_element = riddle[e]
        print(e)
        print(req_element)
        if req_element == '?':
            if e == 0:
                successor_element = riddle[e+1]
            if e  == j-1:
                predecessor_element = riddle[e-1] 
            if (e!= 0) and (e != j-1):
                successor_element = riddle[e+1]
                predecessor_element = riddle [e-1]
            my_pre_succ_elements.extend(successor_element)
            my_pre_succ_elements.extend(predecessor_element)
            required_list = list(set(my_pre_succ_elements)^set(my_replacers))
            substitutor = required_list[0]
            riddle = str(riddle[0:e]) + str(substitutor) + str(riddle[e + 1:])
    print(riddle)
    pass
```

Comment: Based on your spec, there are a nearly infinite number of solutions to this.  "aaa" would be an acceptable solution for "???".  Your code uses "aei" as the substitution list.  Is that a requirement?  You didn't say so.

Comment: Why can't both `?` be replaced with `a` in the first "riddle"? I'm not convinced you've explained all the "rules".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close.  This should work:

```
        if req_element == '?':
            possibles = ['a','e','i']
            if e > 0 and riddle[e-1] in possibles:
                possibles.remove(riddle[e-1])
            if e < j-1 and riddle[e+1] in possibles:
                possibles.remove(riddle[e+1])
            substitutor = possibles[0]
            riddle = riddle[:e] + substitutor + riddle[e+1:]
```

Comment: Tsk, this is something you should have been able to figure out.  Replace your `print(riddle)` with `return riddle`.  And, of course, the `pass` is useless.